# I'm trying to add a data layer in kepler.gl using react, but my data layer is not showing layer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kepler.gl

I'm trying to add a cluster layer in kepler.gl map programmatically for the first time when the data is dispatched on the map, but I'm not able to see any layer so need help with that

```
        dispatch(
                addDataToMap({
                datasets: {
                    info: {
                    label: "Vehicle Data",
                    id: "action",
                    },
                    data: transformedData,
                },
                option: {
                    centerMap: true,
                    readOnly: false,
                },
                config: {
                    version: "v1",
                    config: {
                    visState: {
                        layers: [
                        {
                            type: "cluster",
                            config: {
                            id: "action",
                            columns: {
                                lat: "latitude",
                                lon: "longitude",
                            },
                            isVisible: true,
                            },
                        },
                        ],
                    },
                    },
                },
                })
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make datasets as a array...

Comment: hi, please could you edit your answer to explain in more detail? thank you in advance